# Apollo refetch does not make a request after network error

Tags: typescript, react-native, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

**Context**

We are currently developing a React Native iOS app with a Graphql back-end. Within this app we would like to show the user a modal when there is no internet connection or when the API is down.

Since we are using Apollo and `graphql-code-generator`, we have a generated hook in the component that retrieves the data. We show the modal when the hook returns a network error. If a network error has been found, the `refetch` method from the hook is used to poll and see whether the network or API is back up.

**The Problem**

This unfortunately does not seem to work, calls to the `refetch` method after the network has been reestablished do not result in requests. The `refetch` method also throws a network error.

**Code**

```
function useConnectionStatusPolling() {
  // 'useData' is a custom wrapper around the generated hook, that maps and deserialises fields.
  const { loading, refetch, error } = useData();

  // While refreshing, error.networkError is reset.But we would like
  // to keep the error status around until the request works again.
  //
  // For that, we keep the error in the mutable reference, and update it
  // only when the status it not loading. For loading, keep the
  // previous value.
  const networkError = useRef(false);
  if (!loading) {
    networkError.current = !!error?.networkError;
  }

  // Polling is done manually via useInterval because the builtin polling stops
  // if a network error is thrown which we want to ignore in our case.
  useInterval(refetch, networkError.current ? 5000 : "pause");
  return networkError.current;
}
```

```
/**
 * Executes a callback at each interval.
 * https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/
 * @param callback Method to execute after each delay.
 * @param delay Time in miliseconds.
 */
export function useInterval(callback: () => void, delay: number | "pause") {
  const savedCallback = useRef<() => void>();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current?.();
    }
    if (delay !== "pause") {
      const id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}
```

**Research & Attempts**

We did find out that the error is not cleared as specified in [this article](http://www.petecorey.com/blog/2019/05/13/is-my-apollo-client-connected-to-the-server/). So this hook won't will keep showing the no internet modal and making requests. However this problem still persists after this change, the refetch method just does not make a request to the API. We also tried clearing the cache, but to no avail unfortunately. So I am not really sure what to try at the moment in order to make this work, any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Created a small Expo snack (code snippet) that could recreate the issue in a simpler fashion. Here the problem isn't present! Still have no clue why this problems persists in our app though, so all feedback is welcome!

[snack](https://snack.expo.io/@sebas.thuis/network-error-&-refetch)